# A persistent simple data storage for Node.JS app implementation?

Tags: sql, node.js, database, heroku, storage

I'm planning to launch a simple Node.JS utility and push it to heroku. A fire and forget solution, will sleep for like 90% of the time probably. Unfortunately it seems that I require a persistent data storage for my purposes (heroku apps get rebooted daily and storing everything in RAM is unrealistic), and I don't know which way to look as:

1. Most SQL hostings are paid / limited time free / require constant refreshing ( like freemysqlhosting ).
2. Storing stuff in plain `.txt` format is seemingly hard to implement, besides `git` always overwrites the contents of a tracked `.txt` file, and leaving it untracked disposes of it on heroku and leads to `ENOENT No such file` error. Yeah, I tried.

So, the question is - how do I implement a simple and built in solution for storing data? Are there any relevant typical solutions? It's going to be equivalent to just 1 SQL table.

As you can see, you can answer this on many levels - maybe suggest a free deploy and forget SQL hosting (it obviously has to support external connections), maybe tell me how to keep a file tracked in `git` without actually replacing all of its content with every commit, maybe suggest some module to install. I hope this is not too broad..

Comment: you should look into sqllite

Comment: @DZDomi I think I should indeed do that! It got me at "serverless" and "zero configuration" haha. Thanks for that pointer, I will do just that.

Comment: @DZDomi Just looked into it and [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3) says that sqlite for heroku is not ideal, as the db will be cleared at least every 24 hours. They suggest postgres. I think I will look into that instead, but thanks for the lead <3

Comment: I used to used *mLab* and it has free plan

Comment: @Max Thanks! Already registering an account there, fingers crossed it will work!

Comment: How about Amazon S3? Heroku recommends it too. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

Comment: @Shiva Oh, cool. Will give it a go. Right now utilizing mLab, but I'll check other options out. I didn't have any just yesterday xD